# Powershell Regex to Replace Underscores with Hyphens

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to find a powershell command to search all files in a directory and replace any underscores with hyphens in relative links only (link can't start with http).

Here is an example:

```
<a href="/always_sunny/is_the_best/">
```

should become

```
<a href="/always-sunny/is-the-best/">
```

However, I would like the regex to ignore href values that begin with http. So a link like this should be ignored.

```
<a href="http://thundergunexpress/always_sunny/"
```

Below is the current Powershell command and regex I have been working with. This regex seems to  partially work in Notepad ++ to find and replace underscores but doesn't exclude absolute links. However, the regex isn't working at all in powershell but I am not sure if this is due to the regex or my limited knowledge of Powershell. Any help with the Powershell command and the regex would be greatly appreciated.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path k:\toolbox\powershell\ -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern '(\bhref="|(?!^)\G)[^"<_]*\K_'){(Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace '(\bhref="|(?!^)\G)[^"<_]*\K_', '-'}) | Set-Content $_}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note PCRE is not so similar to .NET regex when it comes to matching some multiple occurrences of a pattern in between two delimiters.

An "idiomatic" way to do that in .NET regex is to use a non-fixed width lookbehind pattern. Here, you can use

```
(?<=\bhref="(?!http)[^"]*?)_(?=[^"]*")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cbhref%3D%22%28%3F!http%29%5B%5E%22%5D*%3F%29_%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29&i=%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Falways_sunny%2Fis_the_best%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fthundergunexpress%2Falways_sunny%2F%22%3E&r=-). Details:

- `(?<=\bhref="(?!http)[^"]*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a `href="`, not followed with `http`, and then any zero or more chars other than `"`, as few as possible
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(?=[^"]*")` - immediately followed with zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char.

Comment: I noticed an issue with this I was hoping you could help me with. Is there a way to only target href attributes that are located within <a> tags? Currently this will target href tags anywhere (ex: in <script> tags). Thanks!

Comment: @Brian `(?<=<a(?:\s[^<>]*?)?\bhref="(?!http)[^"]*?)_(?=[^"]*")` [will do](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3ca%28%3f%3a%5cs%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*%3f%29%3f%5cbhref%3d%22%28%3f!http%29%5b%5e%22%5d*%3f%29_%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%29&i=%3cimg+href%3d%22%2falways_sunny%2fis_the_best%2f%22+%2f%3e%0d%0a%3ca+href%3d%22%2falways_sunny%2fis_the_best%2f%22%3e%0d%0a%3ca+href%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fthundergunexpress%2falways_sunny%2f%22%3e&r=-).